# Como ajustar un boton de Bootstrap al lado de un input

Tags: html, html5, bootstrap

Hola tengo un probrema al ajustar un boton de bootstrap con un input el input me queda algo asi 
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y se supone que tiene que quedar asi

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

con el ojo al lado disculpen que mi pregunta pero realmente no se como ajustarlo, este el el codigo que estoy usando `

```
                                 <label>Ingrese Contraseña</label>
                                 <div class="input-group">
                                <input ID="txtPassword" type="Password" Class="form-control">
                                <button id="show_password" class="btn btn-success" type="button" onclick="mostrarPassword()"> 
                                <span class="fa fa-eye-slash icon"></span> </button>
                                </div>
                                </div>
                                </div>
```

`

Comment: ¿Que versión de Bootstrap es? (pregunto porque en Bootstrap 3 y 4 los `input-group` tienen distinta implementación)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Falta el span **input-group-btn** que agrupa al botón

```html
<link href="https://fontawesome.com/v4.7.0/assets/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<label>Ingrese Contraseña</label>

<div class="input-group">
  <input ID="txtPassword" type="Password" class="form-control">
  <span class="input-group-btn">
    <button id="show_password" class="btn btn-success" type="button" onclick="mostrarPassword()"> 
      Falta el icono<span class="fa fa-eye-slash icon"></span>
    </button>
  </span>
</div>
```

Ejemplo para boostrap 3

```html
<link href="https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="col-lg-3">
  <div class="input-group">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search for...">
    <span class="input-group-btn">
      <button class="btn btn-default" type="button">Go!</button>
    </span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Ejemplo para boostrap 4

```html
<link href="https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="input-group mb-3">
  <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Recipient's username" aria-label="Recipient's username" aria-describedby="button-addon2">
  <div class="input-group-append">
    <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary" type="button" id="button-addon2">Button</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<label>
    Ingrese Contraseña</label>
<div class="input-group">
    <input id="txtPassword" type="Password" class="form-control"/>
    <div class="input-group-append">
        <button id="show_password" class="btn btn-success" type="button" onclick="mostrarPassword()">
            <span class="fa fa-eye-slash icon"></span>
        </button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: No amigo sigue igual

Comment: Hice un cambio en la respuesta pon la etiqueta button dentro de otro div

Answer (score 0):

El problema es que la clase `input-group` tiene `display:table`.  Puedes agregar una clase extra y modificar el css asi:

```css
.password {
  display: "block";
}

#txtPassword {
  width: 236px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

<!-- jQuery library -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<label>Ingrese Contraseña</label>
                                 <div class="input-group password">
                                <input ID="txtPassword" type="Password" Class="form-control" />
                                <button id="show_password" class="btn btn-success" type="button" onclick="mostrarPassword()"> 
                                <span class="fa fa-eye-slash icon"></span> </button>
                                </div>
```